# Apache velocity IncludeTool - conditional include

Tags: java, parsing, include, conditional-statements, velocity

I have a template that will include with #parse other templates.
The problem is that I don't know that the file I'm trying to parse alwais exists.

I've foud the IncludeTool class in the velocity-tools-2.0.jar, I've added as a variable but still when he must test it fails.
Can someone tell me how to add the IncludeTool to my template?

```
    private VelocityContext transmitParameters(params prm){
    VelocityContext c = new VelocityContext();
    //transmit parameters one by one
      c.put("program_name", prm.getProgram_name());
      c.put("date", new DateTool());
      c.put("incl", new IncludeTool());
    return c;
}

 public generate(params prm) {
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, constants.TEMPLATE_PATH);
        ve.init();
        context = new VelocityContext(transmitParameters(p));
        writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);
}
```

And the template

```
#if($incl.exists("templates/$record.name/file.vm"))
#parse("$record.name/file.vm")
#end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new class with the exists function (as David Vonka suggested)

```
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;

public class existTemplate {
    private VelocityEngine engine;
    public existTemplate(VelocityEngine e) {
        engine =new VelocityEngine();
        engine = e;
    }

    public boolean exists(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            // checks for both templates and static content
            return engine.resourceExists(name);
        }
        // make sure about this...
        catch (ResourceNotFoundException rnfe)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (NullPointerException rnfe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and then used it when sending the parameters

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.init();
incl = new existTemplate(ve);

VelocityContext c = new VelocityContext();
c.put("date", new DateTool());
c.put("incl", incl);
```

inside tempalte is used like :

```
#if($incl.exists("$record.name/file.vm"))
#parse("$record.name/file.vm")
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

What definitely seems strange to me is the difference in path. One of the includes templates/, the other does not. I would tend to try

```
#if($incl.exists("$record.name/file.vm"))
#parse("$record.name/file.vm")
#end
```

If that does not work, there are some things to try

1. can you run #parse("fakerecord/file.vm") without the test of existence, if the file exists in the fakerecord folder ?
2. put $incl.getClass().getCanonicalName() in your template. What does it print ?

Comment: 1. if the file exists the parse is working fine. But I don't want to create empty templates so that the #parse function works 
2. This it prints: org.apache.velocity.tools.view.IncludeTool

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at  
org.apache.velocity.tools.view.IncludeTool.exists(IncludeTool.java:192)  </br>


Inside IncludeTool.java
`public boolean exists(String name)
{ try
        {
            // checks for both templates and static content
            return engine.resourceExists(name);
        }
        // make sure about this...
        catch (ResourceNotFoundException rnfe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Here is the initialization of the engine:  
`VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();  
  ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, constants.TEMPLATE_PATH);
        ve.init();`

Comment: It is an initialization problem. You first need to get a ViewToolContext vtc = new ViewToolContext(engine, httpRequest, httpResponse, servletContext) and then configure your IncludeTool by calling incl.configure(vtc) before you put incl into the velocity context.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems to me that even setting httpRequest, httpResponse and servletContext all to null should work if all you need is the exist method, if you do not have access to their values.

Comment: Can't use httpRequest, Response because I'm not using velocity in J2EE so I don't have these classes.  
Error:(17, 12) java: cannot access javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
  class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not found

Comment: well, then I suggest you take the exists method and make it a part of your own public class MyIncludeTool { private VelocityEngine ve; MyIncludeTool(VelicityEngine ve) {this.ve=ve} public boolean exists(String name){ .... }} and put this in your velicity context instead of the IncludeTool instance.